# xsd.exe to generate classes as separate files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd

I have a collection of .xsd files. 
When generating classes using xsd.exe, the output file is some ~17000 lines long with hundreds and hundreds of partial classes.

In the interest of neatness, is it possible for either xsd.exe or even visual studio (2010) to split these classes, each into a separate file?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any possibility using xsd.exe or plain VS, but it is possible using [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper). Right-click on the file -> Refactor -> Move types into matching files.

Comment: wish I could +1 this about 100 times

Comment: @BlackICE, I agree 1,000%, the folks at Microsoft should be slapped HARD for building in such an idiotic limitation.

Comment: Oh man, I wish ReSharper worked for me to do this. MISMO 3.3.1 sucks, and creates a CS file > 350,000 lines of code. ReSharper pukes all over on my machine and can't handle it.

Comment: @Gromer, you should be able to manually split this into ten different files which then should work with RS

Comment: Or, just compile it into its own assembly and reference the assembly