# XSD deserialization generates a mess of partial classes

Tags: c#, xsd, schema, deserialization, partial-classes

I have 12 quite complex schemas that I want to de-serialize. They form a kind of hierarchy, making use in each of them of the definitions of other(s). So I use the XML Schema Definition Tool like this, with the dependencies following the schema to be deserialized:

```
xsd.exe /c schema.xsd importedSchema1.xsd importedSchema2.xsd     importedSchema3.xsd importedSchema4.xsd
```

and the result is something like:

```
schema.cs
schema_importedSchema1.cs
schema_importedSchema1_importedSchema2.cs
schema_importedSchema1_importedSchema2_importedSchema3.cs
schema_importedSchema1_importedSchema2_importedSchema3_importedSchema4.cs
```

And they're full of partial classes. There exists a way to avoid this?
I'm newbie with C# and it's the first time I play with serialization, so I thought that maybe I'm missing something out. All the examples I find are too simple, I can't find a complex situation like this. So I don't know what is exactly happening here, if there is a better way to make it or how I'm supposed to make use of these classes if they're splitted like this. Some suggestions?

Comment: Either generate the Serialize classes yourself or manually edit the generated ones combining the partial classes.

Comment: Serialize manually is not an option -is a *huge* hierarchy. I could consider your 2nd option. But it would be days of manual work too and the schemas could change over time, so it would be nice to automate this process. Each of my schemas define a package with many classes. But I end up with a public partial class ClassA { declared in 20 different files. In each one of those files there are classes of different packages. If the compiler is able to find  things in such a mess I won't change a comma, but some of the declarations are identical in different files.

Comment: Write a tool to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a very clear explanation of what was happening to me:

[XSD Gen Classes That Reference a Common Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328410/xsd-gen-classes-that-reference-a-common-type)

But the answer that best suited to me was this:

[xsd.exe to generate classes as separate files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315129/xsd-exe-to-generate-classes-as-separate-files)

Is not exactly what I wanted (I wanted all the types defined in a xsd in a single file), but anyway, that tool is a great help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking 'why are they **partial** classes', the answer is [here](http://dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2010/05/correctly-creating-classes-using-xsdexe.html):

> "Don’t forget that classes created by xsd.exe are all partial classes.
>   It’s a good idea to add default constructors and logic in a separate
>   partial class in a different file. It’s especially helpful for
>   initializing arrays since xsd.exe generated classes use arrays and not
>   ArrayLists or Generic Lists. This allows you to add logic, that won’t
>   be changed when the class is regenerated."

But, personally, I found the naming conventions of the auto-generated stuff to be ridiculous so I'm just going to need to tough it out in the future, using the auto-generated stuff as a guide to update my classes.